# How can I make a multi-line EditText use the remaining space of a Linear or RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I know about layout_weight and other tricks but problems happen when my EditText becomes too big to fit on one line.

Let's say I have a checkbox, the editText and an arrow imageView, I want something like this, with the checkbox left aligned, and the arrow right aligned:

```
*   |Some very long text that  |  >
    |wraps                     |
```

But my EditText scrolls instead of wrapping.

I'm open to using RelativeLayouts or any other layout, I would just prefer avoiding nesting too many layouts.

EDIT: My XML as of now looks like below. I already tried using RelativeLayout without success.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp">
<Checkbox android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"/>
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:background="@null"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="textImeMultiLine|textCapSentences"
    android:singleLine="false"
    android:textColor="@color/dark_gray"
    android:textColorHint="@color/medium_gray"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:drawable="@drawable/check/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0"
    android:src="@drawable/arrow" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please consider posting your actual layout XML resource, rather than expecting everyone to guess all of the attribute values that you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this idea will work:

Use a RelativeLayout, set checkBox to alignParentLeft, set arrow to alignParentRight and set the following properties on EditText:

set its width to match_parent, height to wrap_content, toRightOf checkBox and toLeftOf arrow.

Maybe this will solve your issue

I was talking about this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
android:paddingTop="8dp" >

<Checkbox
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/right"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/left"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @mbonnin try this one. :)

Comment: Nope, does not work. Not only, do I have the EditText not wraping (it scrolls instead) but in addition, the arrow is not shown.

Comment: Try adding this to your EditText xml then :

android:inputType="textMultiLine"

Comment: Thanks,the textMultiline thing was the missing piece. It works now.